# How to specify tags when uploading video to Facebook using the Graph API

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to upload videos to Facebook successfully using the latest Graph API via Objective-C. However, I'd like to also tag certain Facebook users who are in the video. I cannot get this to work.

The [FB documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) says that there is a "tag" field that accepts an array of objects containing id and name fields. However, if I try to pass a JSON string in this format the video upload fails, without any useful error message. Am I passing the tags data correctly?

Here's sample code that fails. The code succeeds when I remove the @"tags" field from params, or set tagStr to an empty array, i.e. @"[]".

```
NSString *tagStr = @"[{\"id\":\"<id-removed>\", \"name\":\"<name-removed>\"}]";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              data, @"video.mov",
                              @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                              titleStr, @"title",
                              descStr, @"description",
                              tagStr, @"tags",          // specifying tags fails
                              nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Params Dictionary Should be like this,

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Birthday wishes", @"title",
                                   @"via Birthday wishes", @"description",facebook.accessToken,@"access_token",
                                   nil];
```

After the Video gets posted,you can able to tag friends in - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result as like

`[APP.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags/%@?access_token=%@", photoID, [ar_tID objectAtIndex:i], APP.facebook.accessToken]andParams:nilandHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`